# Is it possible to parse objects with the trailing key being a number, in Angular component.html?

Tags: angular

I am pulling some data from a server where the returned value is an array of objects but the object keys are not names but numbers. Something like:

```
[
  {
    "0": 1,
    "1": 1,
    "2": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "3": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "0": 1,
    "1": 2,
    "2": "qui est esse",
    "3": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }
]
```

The keys represent columns in a database such as userId, id, title and body respectively, for example.
Inside an angular component I am looping through the returned array of objects and trying to display the values, like so...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.1}}
</div>
```

But I get

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '0.1' at column x
```

Is there any way I can get those values to be displayed without any errors? Any help would be great.

Comment: Access them like `{{item['1']}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access them in the same way you access basic array indexes

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item['1']}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngFor="let itemObj of item | keyvalue">
      key {{itemObj.key}} -- value {{itemObj.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyvalue-pipe-example)